# Ghost - PrismJS syntax highlighting not working after updating to Ghost 1.0

Tags: ghost-blog, ghost, prismjs

I'm running a Ghost blog hosted on Ghost.io.

[They're currently running a system-wide update](https://blog.ghost.org/1-0/) from Ghost 0.11 to Ghost 1.0.

The update went fine, but I've lost the PrismJS syntax highliting. The code blocks all share the same look - black over creamy-white.

My default.hbs seems to be setup correctly:

```
{{!-- Styles'n'Scripts --}}
...
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset "css/prism.css"}}" />

...
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset "js/prism.js"}}"></script> --}}
...
</body>
```

I have not changed the way I marked my code blocks:

````
```language-java
import com.package.test;
```
````

I've looked at Chrome dev console - there seems to be no errors.

Any leads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the page source I've found out that all of my code blocks had the similar tags:

```
<pre class=" language-language"><code class="-java language-language">
```

The *language-language* part got me a bit suspicious.

### TL;DR

So - apparently the Ghost team has [switched markdown editors](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/issues/2675) when updating to Ghost 1.x. The new editor adds the *language-* prefix automatically. So the code blocks should look like this:

````
```java
import com.package.test;
```
````

And the resulting HTML:

```
<pre class=" language-java"><code class=" language-java">
```

More info: https://www.devsbedevin.net/sytnax-highliting-with-prismjs-on-ghost-1-0/

Comment: do you have big amount of post for change. because I already imported more than hundred and I was thinking about DB update or delete and reimport all (first cleaning the language- )

Comment: That's a good question. I would advise opening a new SO question for this issue. My post count was low enough to do things manually. I would expect a larger count would require something automatic.

Comment: I'll test both ways. First DB and then the other one. And will see what is best in my case.